# What is the limit number of request per day for UPS Address Validation Street Level API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ups, ups-api

I have downloaded UPS Address Validation Street Level API and tried it for my ASP.NET MVC project, but I couldn't see to find out about this info: What is the limit number of request per day?

Comment: try to ask [here](https://www.ups.com/us/en/help-support-center.page?)

Comment: I tried to read through their pdf guide, no luck finding out that info.

Comment: The link above contains a live chat with support team. Try to ask them.